# Issue merging changes between multiple MOCs on new database

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have an IOS app that uses a core database to store
thumbnail photo images and their user selected rating.
I use multiple managed object contexts for this.

The problem is that when the app is installed and
launched for the first time (and thus creates a new
database) the main MOC does not see updates from the
temporary MOC that is making changes to the photo rating.
However on subsequent launches of the app (i.e. database
exists already), everything works fine each and every
time.

And additionally, on a new app launch, even though the
ratings don't show up in the main viewcontroller, I know
they're being saved to disk, because on a app re-launch
I see the ratings the user had entered.

The main MOC is a list view controller that displays the
photos. When the user selects a photo from the list, it
launches another view controller (with a temporary MOC
tied to the same persistent store) where the user selects
a photo rating. But on a fresh launch of the app, the photo
rating setting never propagates back to the list view controller.

I've included some code. Would appreciate any insights.

### Database creation in main listview controller

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[urlForPhotosDb path]]) {

if (photosDB.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
   [photosDB openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

        ......(additional code here).........

}];     
}
} else {
[photosDB saveToURL:urlForPhotosDb forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
[PhotosDatabase populatePhotosDb];

......(additional code here).........
];
}

return photosDB;
}
```

### On View Load in main listView controller

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


[PhotosDatabase getPhotosDbForOpenBlock:^(UIManagedDocument  *doc) {
self.psc = [doc.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator];
[self setupFetchedResultsController:doc];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(contextSaved:)
                                      name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                      object:nil];
}];
}
```

### Setting up of temporary MOC in delegate method of main

### listview controller called from secondary view controller

```
-(void)didSelectPhotoRating:(NSDictionary *)photoInfo Rating:(NSNumber *)rating
{
NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[newContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.psc];
Photos *photo = [Photos findPhoto:photoInfo
           inManagedObjectContext:newContext];
if (photo) {
photo.rating = rating;
NSError *error;
[newContext save:&error];
}

}
```

### method in main listview controller to merge changes

```
-(void)contextSaved:(NSNotification *)notification
{
if ([notification object] != self.document.managedObjectContext) {
    [self.document.managedObjectContext

mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
[self performFetch];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
}
```

And in the contextSaved method above, the notification
indeed contains the user selected rating for the photo.
But it doesn't reflect in the main listview controller.

Answer (score 0):

Start using nested contexts. It's just much much much much much easier and in sync on every possible level. The have not updated the core data programming guide to cover it well at this point.

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/